# Undefined index: oauth_token using Consolibyte QuickBooks PHP DevKit

Tags: php, oauth, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

I am using the Quickbooks PHP DevKit from   github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php

Am getting the following error page after clicking on Connect to Quickbooks icon:

> Notice: Undefined index: oauth_token in
>   /srv/disk14/2290833/www/qbstream.scienceontheweb.net/QuickBooks/IPP/IntuitAnywhere.php
>   on line 468
>
> Notice: Undefined index: oauth_token_secret in
>   /srv/disk14/2290833/www/qbstream.scienceontheweb.net/QuickBooks/IPP/IntuitAnywhere.php
>   on line 468
>
> Notice: Undefined index: oauth_token in
>   /srv/disk14/2290833/www/qbstream.scienceontheweb.net/QuickBooks/IPP/IntuitAnywhere.php
>   on line 485
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /srv/disk14/2290833/www/qbstream.scienceontheweb.net/QuickBooks/IPP/IntuitAnywhere.php:468)
>   in
>   /srv/disk14/2290833/www/qbstream.scienceontheweb.net/QuickBooks/IPP/IntuitAnywhere.php
>   on line 443

I added some print statements to index.php to show that the SQL database is connecting and storing variables from my edited config.php: 
http://qbstream.scienceontheweb.net/docs/partner_platform/example_app_ipp_v3/index.php

- mcrypt php extension is installed, you can run phpinfo.php at the above url

Attached are my development keys and development settings at developer.intuit.com (pic of settings appended to keys as I am allowed only 2 links in this post):

[dev keys & settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4X7t5.png)

Here is my config.php

```
    <?php

/**
 * Intuit Partner Platform configuration variables
 * 
 * See the scripts that use these variables for more details. 
 * 
 * @package QuickBooks
 * @subpackage Documentation
 */

// Turn on some error reporting
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// Require the library code
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../../QuickBooks.php';
//require_once('/home/www/qbstream.scienceontheweb.net/QuickBooks.php');


// Your application token (Intuit will give you this when you register an Intuit Anywhere app)
$token = '99cbe16bba521b4f25b99cbb4ad297910a33';

// Your OAuth consumer key and secret (Intuit will give you both of these when you register an Intuit app)
// 
// IMPORTANT:
//  To pass your tech review with Intuit, you'll have to AES encrypt these and 
//  store them somewhere safe. 
// 
// The OAuth request/access tokens will be encrypted and stored for you by the 
//  PHP DevKit IntuitAnywhere classes automatically. 
$oauth_consumer_key = 'qyprdq1tdxuG9uvFFY4dQnNWtrA8a3';
$oauth_consumer_secret = 'qKK95MELeifFxcxuy7zeApvtncRcQfYtmYS9TCHi';


// If you're using DEVELOPMENT TOKENS, you MUST USE SANDBOX MODE!!!  If you're in PRODUCTION, then DO NOT use sandbox.
$sandbox = true;     // When you're using development tokens
//$sandbox = false;    // When you're using production tokens


// This is the URL of your OAuth auth handler page
//$quickbooks_oauth_url = 'http://quickbooks.v3.com:8888/quickbooks-php/docs/partner_platform/example_app_ipp_v3/oauth.php';
$quickbooks_oauth_url = 'http://qbstream.scienceontheweb.net/docs/partner_platform/example_app_ipp_v3/oauth.php';


// This is the URL to forward the user to after they have connected to IPP/IDS via OAuth
//$quickbooks_success_url = 'http://quickbooks.v3.com:8888/quickbooks-php/docs/partner_platform/example_app_ipp_v3/success.php';
$quickbooks_success_url = 'http://qbstream.scienceontheweb.net/docs/partner_platform/example_app_ipp_v3/success.php';


// This is the menu URL script 
//$quickbooks_menu_url = 'http://quickbooks.v3.com:8888/quickbooks-php/docs/partner_platform/example_app_ipp_v3/menu.php';
$quickbooks_menu_url = 'http://qbstream.scienceontheweb.net/docs/partner_platform/example_app_ipp_v3/menu.php';


// This is a database connection string that will be used to store the OAuth credentials 
// $dsn = 'pgsql://username:password@hostname/database';
// $dsn = 'mysql://username:password@hostname/database';
$dsn = mysqli_connect("etc,etc,etc,etc");


// You should set this to an encryption key specific to your app
$encryption_key = 'bcde1234';

// Do not change this unless you really know what you're doing!!!  99% of apps will not require a change to this.
$the_username = 'DO_NOT_CHANGE_ME';

// The tenant that user is accessing within your own app
$the_tenant = 12345;

// Initialize the database tables for storing OAuth information
if (!QuickBooks_Utilities::initialized($dsn))
{
    // Initialize creates the neccessary database schema for queueing up requests and logging
    QuickBooks_Utilities::initialize($dsn);
}

// Instantiate our Intuit Anywhere auth handler 
// 
// The parameters passed to the constructor are:
//  $dsn                    
//  $oauth_consumer_key     Intuit will give this to you when you create a new Intuit Anywhere application at AppCenter.Intuit.com
//  $oauth_consumer_secret  Intuit will give this to you too
//  $this_url               This is the full URL (e.g. http://path/to/this/file.php) of THIS SCRIPT
//  $that_url               After the user authenticates, they will be forwarded to this URL
// 
$IntuitAnywhere = new QuickBooks_IPP_IntuitAnywhere($dsn, $encryption_key, $oauth_consumer_key, $oauth_consumer_secret, $quickbooks_oauth_url, $quickbooks_success_url);

// Are they connected to QuickBooks right now? 
if ($IntuitAnywhere->check($the_username, $the_tenant) and 
    $IntuitAnywhere->test($the_username, $the_tenant))
{
    // Yes, they are 
    $quickbooks_is_connected = true;

    // Set up the IPP instance
    $IPP = new QuickBooks_IPP($dsn);

    // Get our OAuth credentials from the database
    $creds = $IntuitAnywhere->load($the_username, $the_tenant);

    // Tell the framework to load some data from the OAuth store
    $IPP->authMode(
        QuickBooks_IPP::AUTHMODE_OAUTH, 
        $the_username, 
        $creds);

    if ($sandbox)
    {
        // Turn on sandbox mode/URLs 
        $IPP->sandbox(true);
    }

    // Print the credentials we're using
    //print_r($creds);

    // This is our current realm
    $realm = $creds['qb_realm'];

    // Load the OAuth information from the database
    $Context = $IPP->context();

    // Get some company info
    $CompanyInfoService = new QuickBooks_IPP_Service_CompanyInfo();
    $quickbooks_CompanyInfo = $CompanyInfoService->get($Context, $realm);
}
else
{
    // No, they are not
    $quickbooks_is_connected = false;
}
```

Please help me connect to intuit.  Thank you.

Comment: Post your code. Post a screenshot of your sandbox/dev application configuration within developer.intuit.com. Make sure you have the PHP mcrypt extension installed.

Comment: Hi Keith, I have edited the original post with the information you asked for. Please take a look.

Comment: @cirrus you managed to sort the issue? are you using any platform such as laravel etc?